# LINQ stack size problems

Tags: performance, linq, delegates

I have one question, in my company we are using Toxicity report to measure static code using reflector code metric as an input for Toxicity Report tool, and obviously i can see the disassembler of the code. I'm using LINQ to Objects and to XML to make my code clear but i start facing some stack size issues. I saw the disassembled code and i start seeing that where i include the "where" linq clause it generates a delegate and also creates a method, increasing obviously my stack size because is creating more methods. Does anyone knows how can i get rid of the delegates? here it's an example:

Source code:

```
List<XElement> toolPnP = 
(from c in xPnpInfo.Descendants("assignedSupport")
 where c != null
 select c).ToList();
```

Disassemble code:

```
List<XElement> toolPnP = xPnpInfo.Descendants((XName) ("assignedSupport")).Where<XElement>(delegate (XElement c) {
 return (c != null);
 }).ToList<XElement>();
```

these delegate is pointing to:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private static bool <.ctor>b__2(XElement c)
{
    return (c != null);
}
```

how can i get rid of that, any recommendation will be really welcome.

Comment: what "stack size" problem do you have and is this real or imagined?

Comment: This seems like premature optimization. Linq is entirely based on using delegates, I don't think you're gonna get out of that outside of using a regular for loop.

Comment: yup it was real, and stack size problems is that the stack size is increasing because the creation of methods (compiler generated). It seems like as rossisdead mentioned Linq is based on delegates and delegates uses methods, so I can create them or let the compiler to generate the methods in any case the methods will be created increasing the stack size of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the trivially snarky answer (Descendents property isn't going to give you null results, so you don't need to test that), no... you can't use linq's where without a method call.

The compiler translates the where to a call to `System.Linq.Enumerable.Where` which requires a method reference.  You can write the method yourself if you don't like compiler generated methods, but there must be a method if you are using where.

```
Func<XElement, bool> myFunc = this.FilterMethod;
List<XElement> result = xPnpInfo.Descendants("assignedSupport")
  .Where(myFunc)
  .ToList();
```

...

```
public bool FilterMethod(XElement source)
{
  return source != null;
}
```